# List interpolation for a list of datetime/values

Tags: c#, math, numbers, timestamp, interpolation

Forgive me if I'm using the wrong terminology, as I'm not 100% certain what I want to do is the right thing to do, or even the correct terminology for it.

I have a list of entities with a timestamp and a value to it. The interval of the timestamps aren't similar, for instance the first one might be at 1:00:02, the next at 1:00:03, and then at 1:00:10.

In order to get decent information out of the data, I will need to have it all "spaced" evenly. Enter interpolation. This basically means that I will insert values in between the "unbalanced" different timespans, in order to produced a proper set of data. It all seems pretty simple.

My problem comes in when I try to find -what- values to inject, as the timestamp is a datetime, and the milliseconds is making it difficult to calculate when/what to use.

My first solution is to round everything to seconds, and write off the miliseconds (which I can live with), and then just injecting values for each second, with the value being the average of the two existing valid values, at a given time.

The alternative, which I cant seem to figure out how to do, or find a solution online for, is by finding the lowest common denominator, given N values.

Any recommendations, ideas or corrections?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you would find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672998/resample-aggregate-and-interpolate-of-timeseries-trend-data, especially the answer with a LINQ implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "lowest common denominator" I understand you to refer **not** to LCD in the typical mathematical sense, but rather the "smallest timing difference between timestamps".

If so, one approach would be:

1. Construct a list of all [pairwise timing differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945272/check-difference-in-seconds-between-two-times) of the N timestamps.
2. Select the minimum from that list.

For your example, the list of pairwise timing differences would be: `0:01, 0:07, 0:08`. The "lowest common denominator would be `0:01`, or 1 second.

Did I understand your problem correctly?

Comment: Correct. Currently I have a class that constructs with two entities, and contains a "TimeDifference". I create a list of these "Difference" classes from initial list, so then I have a list of all the differences, 0, 7, 8 as per your example. However, I don't think its as simple as that. If I change the example to 0:02, 0;07, 0:08, the "LCD" would not be the smallest (2), but it would still be 1. So, what I need, if I do go this route, would be a function to calculate that.